# Cómo cambiar el nombre de un commit viejo que ya se pusheo?

Tags: github, git-push, git-commit

Hola buenas subi mediante push varios commits de los cuales el segundo necesito cambiarle el nombre porque me olvide de nombrar un archivo creado se puede? el nombre se cambiaria tanto local como remotamente? Para mas informacion todo esto es en un rama secundaria.

Comment: Con `--amend` puedes cambiar el mensaje del último commit (en realidad crea un commit nuevo con este mensaje y el commit original "desaparece"). Pero ese cambio es local. Cuando intentes hacer push no te va a dejar porque el hash del último commit remoto ya no coincide con el de ningún commit local. Puedes forzar el push con la opción `--force`, pero eso puede causar problemas a tus compañeros si trabajaban sobre esa misma rama. Debes avisarles y si aún no han hecho pull de la misma no habrá problema.

Comment: Si no se trata del último commit, `--amend` no te sirve. Pero puedes usar un rebase interactivo. De todas formas tendrás el mismo problema a la hora del push, ya que no sólo invalidarás un commit sino también todos los que venían después, que serán reemplazados por commits nuevos. Deberías usar el push --force con la misma advertencia que en el comentario anterior.

Comment: Perfecto muchisimas gracias!!